# Is the intersection of eqivilent sets still equvilent?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(\Omega , \mathcal B , P)$ be a probability space. Suppose $\{A_n\}$ are all equivalent to $A$ in the sense that $P(A_n \triangle  A) =0$. Im wondering is it true that $P(\left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) \triangle A)=0$? Here is what I have done so far.

\begin{align}P( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n  \triangle A) & = P(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \setminus A) + P(A \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n ) \\ & \le P(A_n \setminus A) + P(A \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n ) \\ &= P(A \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n )
  \end{align}

Can I say $ P(A \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n ) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A \setminus A_n ) $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can say that. Notice that: $$A\setminus \bigcap_n A_n = \bigcup_n (A\setminus A_n),
$$
so:
$$\begin{align}
P(A\setminus \bigcap_n A_n) &= P(\bigcup_n (A\setminus A_n)) \\
 &\le \sum_n P((A\setminus A_n)). \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't notice that

Comment: You're welcome. Better late than never ;)